# Creating Plug-in project in Eclipse programmatically

Tags: eclipse, plugins

I tried to create using eclipse wizard a "Plugin from Existing JAR Archives" and I added an external JAR. When I tried to check the .classpath file I have this

```
<classpath>
     <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.6"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.pde.core.requiredPlugins"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path=""/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.junit.JUNIT_CONTAINER/4"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

How does eclipse know what is the JAR file I am pointing at? 
And can this process be replicated programatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information about the included JARs is in the project's MANIFEST.MF and build.properties files.

You can edit or create these two files using java.util.jar.Manifest and java.util.Properties classes.

Comment: Yeah saw that but I could not find any eclipse how-to on how to create Manifest.mf programmatically.